# Enable Tableview Scrolling but disable touches

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I want to disable my tableview. Means that no button,TextFields and other controls can be touched but also i want that my tableview scroll should be working properly.

```
self.tableView.userInteractionEnabled=true;
```

I have used this but this made scrolling also disable.

Comment: Your view contains only a `tableView`?

Comment: disable user interaction of your cell instead of tableview

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should set the individual `userInteractionEnabled` property of the elements you want disabled of your `UITableView` cells to `NO`, rather than the entire `UITableView`.

For example, `myButton.userInteractionEnabled = NO;`

Setting that to `NO` on the entire `UITableView` disables any gesture recognizers that are used to scroll.

Answer (score 1):

Simply set `userInteractionEnabled` to **false** to your `UITableViewCell`.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
  // do your stuffs
  cell.userInteractionEnabled = false
  return cell
}
```

To disbale selection

```
tableView.allowSelection = false
```

Comment: Would this not also block selection of the cell?

Comment: @IsaRanjha yeah right thx i updated my answer.he didn't mention about selection that's why i didn't palced

Answer (score 1):

You have to set only `isUserInteractionEnabled` & `selectionStyle`

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)

        cell.selectionStyle = .none;
        cell.isUserInteractionEnabled = false;

        return cell
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

try to override UITableView `touchesShouldCancelInContentView` method:

//OC code:

```
- (BOOL)touchesShouldCancelInContentView:(UIView *)view
{
    //when you want to scroll and touch event don't deliver to controls. 
    if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIControl class])){
          return YES;
    }

    return [super touchesShouldCancelInContentView:view];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can disable selection when you started scrolling. Implement `UIScrollViewDelegate`

In `scrollViewWillBeginDragging:`

```
tableView.allowsSelection = NO;
```

In `scrollViewDidEndDragging:willDecelerate:`

```
tableView.allowsSelection = YES;
```

Answer (score 0):

Select tableViewCell and Uncheck The User Interaction Enabled Property
[image]

and Select tableView and Check The Scrolling Enabled Property
[image]
It's Working Fine.