# UITableView didSelect issue with nested UiCollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, select, uicollectionview

I have a tableView with cells that contain UiCollectionView. My didSelect tableView's delegate isn't called when I touch the cell on the collectionView.
I think it's my collectionView that get the touch instead. Do you have any elegant solution to keep the scroll enabled on my collectionView but disable the selection and pass it to the tableview ?

Here is my tableView declaration :

```
private lazy var tableView:UITableView = { [weak self] in
    
    $0.register(TestTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "identifier")
    $0.delegate = self
    $0.dataSource = self
    return $0
    
}(UITableView())
```

Here are my delegate and dataSource methods:

```
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    
    return 20
}

public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "identifier", for: indexPath) as! TestTableViewCell
    return cell
}

public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    
    print(indexPath)
}
```

And here is my cell :

```
public class TestTableViewCell : UITableViewCell {

    private lazy var collectionViewFlowLayout:UICollectionViewFlowLayout = {
    
        $0.scrollDirection = .horizontal
        $0.minimumLineSpacing = 0
        $0.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
        return $0
    
    }(UICollectionViewFlowLayout())
    private lazy var collectionView:UICollectionView = {
    
        $0.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "identifier")
        $0.delegate = self
        $0.dataSource = self
        return $0
    
    }(UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: collectionViewFlowLayout))

    public override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    
        contentView.addSubview(collectionView)
        collectionView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.edges.equalToSuperview()
        }
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
     
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    
        return 5
    }

    public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    
        let cell:UICollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cell:"identifier", for: indexPath) as! cell:UICollectionViewCell
        return cell
    }

    public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    
        return collectionView.frame.size
    }
}
```

If you spot any compilation error, excuse me, this is an anonymized copy/past. My app is running without error.

If you want an example of what I'm trying to do you can check AirBnb's app. TableView with some houses with cells and inside, pictures collectionView. Il you touch the collectionView, the tableView select the cell...

Thanks

Comment: Try to set `isUserInteractionEnabled` collectionView property to `false`

Comment: Thanks but I want to keep the scroll enabled on the collectionView. I edit the question about that

Comment: Try to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44963243/enable-tableview-scrolling-but-disable-touches). It's for `UITableView` but I think you can apply it to `UICollectionView`

Comment: Setting `isUserInteractionEnabled = false` to my collectionViewCells don't work :/

Comment: Your collectionViewCells works, but you want to have double or more clickable views inside the collectionViewCells. When you set the is `UserInteractionEnabled = false` you need to add tapGesture to your view of your collectionViewCell

Comment: Do you do some operations on collectionview didSelect method?

Comment: @Bejil - do you want the tableViewCell selected when the ***collectionViewCell is selected***? Or, do you want it selected when the collectionView is scrolled? Or, when *anywhere* on the collectionView is tapped (tapping/selecting a cell... tapping in between cells... etc)?

Comment: @DonMag I want to tableView didSelect to be fired when I touch anywhere on the cell (includind the collectionView inside), but I want to preserve the collectionView scroll

Comment: @OmerTekbiyik Nope, nothing

Comment: @Bejil - are you also using `didSelectItemAt` on your collection view cells?

Comment: @DonMag No. I added some code to my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there is a "direct" way to do what you're asking. The collection view will respond to the gestures, so they can't "flow through" to the table view / cells without using a closure or protocol/delegate pattern.

Here's one approach...

We subclass `UICollectionView` and, on `touchesBegan` call a closure to tell the table view to select the row.

We can also implement `scrollViewWillBeginDragging` to select the row on collection view scroll, in addition to collection view "tap."

So...

**View Controller class**

```
class TableColTableViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    // number of items in the collection view for each row
    let myData: [Int] = [
        12, 15, 8, 21, 17, 14,
        16, 10, 5, 13, 20, 19,
    ]

    let tableView = UITableView()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(tableView)
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            tableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),
        ])
        
        tableView.register(SomeTableCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "someTableCell")
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
    }
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return myData.count
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "someTableCell", for: indexPath) as! SomeTableCell
        cell.rowTitleLabel.text = "Row \(indexPath.row)"
        cell.numItems = myData[indexPath.row]
        
        // closure for the cell to tell us to select it
        //  because its collection view was tapped
        cell.passThroughSelect = { [weak self] theCell in
            guard let self = self,
                  let pth = self.tableView.indexPath(for: theCell)
            else { return }
            
            self.tableView.selectRow(at: pth, animated: true, scrollPosition: .none)
            
            // selecting a row programmatically does NOT trigger didSelectRowAt
            //  so we'll call our own did select func
            self.myDidSelect(pth)
        }
        return cell
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        // pass this on to our own did select func
        //  so it matches what happens when programmatically selecting the row
        myDidSelect(indexPath)
    }
    
    func myDidSelect(_ indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("Table View - didSelectRowAt", indexPath)
        // do something because the row was selected
    }
}
```

**Table View Cell class**

```
class SomeTableCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    // callback closure
    var passThroughSelect: ((UITableViewCell) -> ())?
    
    var rowTitleLabel = UILabel()
    var collectionView: SubCollectionView!
    var numItems: Int = 0 {
        didSet {
            collectionView.reloadData()
        }
    }
    
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    func commonInit() {
        let fl = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        fl.scrollDirection = .horizontal
        fl.estimatedItemSize = CGSize(width: 120.0, height: 52.0)
        fl.minimumLineSpacing = 12
        fl.minimumInteritemSpacing = 12
        collectionView = SubCollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: fl)
        
        rowTitleLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        contentView.addSubview(rowTitleLabel)
        contentView.addSubview(collectionView)
        
        let g = contentView.layoutMarginsGuide
        
        // avoid auto-layout complaints
        let c = collectionView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60.0)
        c.priority = .required - 1
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            rowTitleLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            rowTitleLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            rowTitleLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            rowTitleLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30.0),
            
            collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rowTitleLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 4.0),
            collectionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            collectionView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            collectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            c,
            
        ])
        
        collectionView.register(SomeCollectionCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "someCollectionCell")
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.delegate = self
        
        collectionView.passThroughTouch = { [weak self] in
            guard let self = self else { return }
            self.passThroughSelect?(self)
        }
        
        collectionView.backgroundColor = .systemYellow
    }
    
}
extension SomeTableCell: UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {
    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return numItems
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "someCollectionCell", for: indexPath) as! SomeCollectionCell
        cell.label.text = "Cell \(indexPath.item)"
        return cell
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("Collection View - didSelectItemAt", indexPath)
    }
}
extension SomeTableCell: UIScrollViewDelegate {
    // if you only want the table cell selected on TAP, don't implement this
    // if you want the table cell selected on CollectionView SCROLL, implement this
    func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        self.passThroughSelect?(self)
    }
}
```

**UICollectionView subclass**

```
class SubCollectionView: UICollectionView {
    var passThroughTouch: (() -> ())?
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        // this allows the collection view cell to be selected
        super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
        // this tells the controller (the table view cell)
        //  that the collection view was tapped
        passThroughTouch?()
    }
}
```

**UICollectionView Cell class**

```
class SomeCollectionCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    
    var label = UILabel()
    var styleView = UIView()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    func commonInit() {
        styleView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        styleView.addSubview(label)
        contentView.addSubview(styleView)

        let g = contentView
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

            styleView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            styleView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            styleView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            styleView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),

            label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: styleView.topAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            label.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: styleView.leadingAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            label.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: styleView.trailingAnchor, constant: -8.0),
            label.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: styleView.bottomAnchor, constant: -8.0),
            
        ])

        label.textColor = .white
        
        styleView.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.5, alpha: 1.0)
        styleView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        styleView.layer.borderWidth = 1
        styleView.layer.cornerRadius = 6

    }

    override var isSelected: Bool {
        didSet {
            label.textColor = isSelected ? .red : .white
            styleView.backgroundColor = isSelected ? UIColor(white: 0.95, alpha: 1.0) : UIColor(white: 0.5, alpha: 1.0)
            styleView.layer.borderColor = isSelected ? UIColor.red.cgColor : UIColor.white.cgColor
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It was my conclusion to. I mark your answer as accepted because it's the most complete

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following

1. First in first, print something in `didSelectItem` of your collectionView delegate, to make ensure that your collectionView cell is tapped.
2. add a delegate property in your `UICollectionViewClass` and call the delegate in the `DidSelectItem` if the step 1 is performing correctly.
3. In your UITableViewController, you have a function `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, here add the delegate property for the associate cell.
4. If you can print something in your delegate function, then you are at your last step. Call `super.didSelect..`with your indexPath, because now you have everything to call didSelect manually.

Comment: No doubt adding custom delegate or closure will work, but I'm sure there is an issue somewhere and that an elegant solution exists. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you would like to try allowsSelection property of UICollectionView. If you set this property false, your collection view cells are not selected any more.

And I think tableView didSelect can capture user interaction. If UITableView still can not capture didSelect, you can give delegate to collectionView and fire it once it's tapped by adding a tap gesture onto UICollectionView.

Comment: `allowsSelection  = false` on collectionView doesn't help :'(